# Can I query both the Table and the Global Secondary Index in KeyConditionExpression

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, indexing, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have this table where I have put a Hash Key on a column called org_id and a Global Secondary Index on a column called ts. And I need to run a query against the table matching the condition, but I am getting the error Query key condition not supported.I can't use the "ts" as a Sort Key because there might be repetition there.
Therefore I wanted to know is it possible to query both the index and table in single condition like I have done below.

```
KeyCondition = Key("org_id").eq("some_id") & 
Key("ts").between(START_DATE,END_DATE)
ProjectionExpression = "ts,val"

response = GET_TABLE.query(
TableName=DYNAMO_TABLE_NAME,
IndexName="ts-index",
    KeyConditionExpression=KeyCondition,
    ProjectionExpression=ProjectionExpression,
    Limit=50
)
```

Comment: *"I can't use the "ts" as a Sort Key because there might be repetition there."*  Are you sure?  [*"In a DynamoDB table, each key value must be unique. However, the key values in a global secondary index do not need to be unique."*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html)

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, Hey thanks a lot man. Didn't know that. Although I still want to know whether we can query both GSI and Table together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible to access base table attributes and from a GSI query.  You have to project the attributes you need, into the GSI.

> You can project other base table attributes into the index if you want. When you query the index, DynamoDB can retrieve these projected attributes efficiently. However, global secondary index queries cannot fetch attributes from the base table.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html

Note that the "primary key" of a GSI doesn't need to be unique.

> In a DynamoDB table, each key value must be unique. However, the key values in a global secondary index do not need to be unique.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html